# Timezone or location to UTC offset

Tags: node.js, timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I need library that can convert time zone to utc offset. I have list of Americans cities, and I know their zones (PST, EST ....) and locations. So my strategy can be

- library.getOffset('city location')
- myLibraryOrOtherLibrary.getOffset('EST')

I know about library moment.js .But library doesn't support all Americans cities for something like below

```
    moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

Should I implement something myself or there is some other library or I can use moment.js in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You cannot get a time zone or offset from an abbreviation alone, because there are ambiguities like `CST` which could be -5, -6, or +8 depending on how you interpret it ("Central Standard Time", "Cuba Standard Time", "China Standard Time").
- You also cannot get a time zone or offset from a city name alone, because there are many cities with the same name in different locations across the world.  For example, `Paris` could mean Paris, France or it could mean Paris, Texas, USA, or [any of the other places called Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_(disambiguation)#Places).  You also might get different spellings of a city for different languages, depending on the city, such as the capital of Ukraine being spelled `Kiev` in English and `Kyiv` in Ukrainian.
- Moment supports the standard list of [IANA time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  They aren't all the cities of the world, but rather a specific string that sometimes is based on a major city name.  There are plenty of exceptions.

Ultimately, the best way to solve this problem is in two steps:

1. Resolve your locations to approximate latitude and longitude coordinates.  This is called *geocoding*, and there are a number of APIs and databases available that can help you with this.  For example, [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).
2. Resolve the coordinates to an IANA time zone identifier.  There are many methods for this, including the [Google Maps Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro), and many others listed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824).   You can then use this identifier with Moment.js and others.