# How to get TimeZone from Country code or city code

Tags: android, timezone, difference

I want to show the difference between two TimeZones, I have city code, city name and country code, a country name so how I can get TimeZone from these codes? Have you an idea about it? Please, guys, help to solve it.

Comment: what have you tried so far? if nothing, then please give it a try and let us know if failed, then we will help you.

Comment: Have a look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234563/country-to-timezone-mapping-database

Comment: In addition to the dup answer, see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327407/634824).  Then read [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824).